# Octaver + Phaser in Boss ME-70?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal

Is there a way to achieve both phaser and octaver in Boss ME-70? They appear to be under the same pedal, is there any trick for it?

Thanks

Comment: Use octaver on expression pedal

Comment: @jeremy this will give you the modified note only, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the manual and trying out several ways, apparently it's impossible to achieve this with this multi-FX.
I hope someone beats my answer and proves me wrong, please comment on.

Comment: I have no experience with this particular pedal but have a Boss ME-50B which functions in a similar way to this unit. I’m not aware of any tricks, you can only select one effect from each category. However if you want octave+phaser you can use the pedal effect for the octave though it might sound different than the pedal effect and I don’t think you can mix the direct signal with the pedal effect.

Answer (score 1):

The manual seems to indicate that, in *memory mode*, you can assign an effect to arbitrary patch (pedal) position using *write mode*. This suggests to me that you can assign any effect to a different patch pedal than the one you'd normally be forced to use in manual mode.

See [Boss ME-70 User Manual](https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/ME-70_egfispd2.pdf) (page 10)

Comment: Can you elaborate because I haven't figured out how to do it, I want to create a patch and store it as a User Preset, so that it has both the effects Octaver AND Phaser enabled, whilst they both are under the same pedal number. I'm not sure you fully understood my question.